# Meteor fails after upgrading node

Tags: node.js, meteor

After upgrading node to v0.8.1, bundled Meteor apps now throw an error:

```
node: symbol lookup error: ~/bundle/server/node_modules/fibers/src/fibers.node:
undefined symbol: _ZNK2v85Value11IsUndefinedEv
```

What's the right way to upgrade node?  Is Meteor compatible with v0.8.1?

Comment: After you upgraded Node, did you reinstall your dependencies with NPM? Fibers has a compiled piece, so it would need to be recompiled. If you have your modules shrinkwrapped with `npm shrinkwrap` you can just `rm -rf node_modules` and then `npm install`.

Comment: Yes, after upgrading node, I ran npm update to get the latest versions of node modules like fibers. That worked fine when running the app directly from the directory in test mode. But using 'meteor bundle' to deploy the app in production failed. Meteor bundles an old version of fibers that doesn't work with the current stable release of node. I fixed the problem by replacing the bundled fibers.node with the version from my local installation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to make it work by replacing

```
~/bundle/server/node_modules/fibers/src/fibers.node
```

with

```
~/.npm/fibers/0.6.8/package/bin/linux-x64-v8-3.11/fibers.node
```

What's the right way to upgrade?

Comment: This seems to be an incompatibility between the latest node and an older versions fibers, the right way to upgrade is to just upgrade through Meteor (which I believe would inform you when there is an upgrade). Of course, if you use Node.js outside of Meteor that doesn't necessarily count; in that case you could get around generating a dev bundle and fixing incompatibilities with the latest fibers as you go, but perhaps that might not be feasible as it is too much work if you don't plan to develop for the Meteor core. Summarized, Meteor prefers "stable" (wrt dependencies) over "latest"...

Comment: It might be that with one of the first future releases, the developments will bump the versions of the dependencies. But given that it's just released, there's no need to hurry...

Comment: I'm on the latest Meteor, 0.3.7, but the fibers provided by Meteor doesn't work with the current stable version of node. Managing dependencies will be a problem for Meteor, since Meteor uses the installed version of node but provides its own versions of node modules. Seems like Meteor can either supply the version of node that matches the bundled modules, or stop bundling the modules with the app. Otherwise there will be dependency hell.

Comment: Meteor **does** come with `node` bundled. However, your system chooses the system `node` instead of the meteor `node`. Note that you can also specify where the modules need to be loaded from, namely by setting the `NODE_PATH` environment variable. You can see node being packed in [admin/generate-dev-bundle.sh](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/admin/generate-dev-bundle.sh), which is unpacked upon running `meteor` and gets packed for release using [admin/build-release.sh](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/admin/build-release.sh).

Comment: I'm using 'meteor bundle' to deploy to a production machine. Meteor doesn't include a node binary in this bundle (nor should it). When you deploy the bundle on a production machine that's using the same version of node as on the development machine, the bundle may not work. This is a problem. It'll be helpful to have some guidance on the right way to upgrade node to avoid dependency issues when bundling applications for production deployment.

Comment: Ah yeah, but in that case the `README` [explicitly says](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/app/lib/bundler.js#L574) what to do: `This is a Meteor application bundle. It has only one dependency, node.js (with the 'fibers' package).` and tells to install Node.js, Fibers and MongoDB. Furthermore, I don't see why having the same version would break it...

Comment: This is exactly the issue. The Meteor application bundle doesn't use the fibers installed with node.js, it uses it's own copy in ~/bundle/server/node_modules/fibers/src/.  If Meteor's version of fibers isn't compatible with the current node.js version, the application crashes. The workaround is to replace Meteor's version of fibers.node.

Comment: From updated Meteor docs: "For now, bundles will only run on the platform that the bundle was created on. To run on a different platform, you'll need to rebuild the native packages included in the bundle. To do that, make sure you have npm available, and run the following:

    $ cd bundle/server/node_modules
    $ rm -r fibers
    $ npm install fibers@0.6.5